# Jetpack Navigation Component handle navigation controller with Bottom Navigation and it's Back Stack navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-architecture

Hello i am developing one application and i am stuck on navigation in Navigation View.

Example I have activity and inside i have define navigation host controller like below

```
    setSupportActionBar(mMainToolbar);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.homeFragment, R.id.questionBankFragment,
            R.id.testFragment, R.id.dailyHuntFragment,
            R.id.liveClassesFragment)
            .setOpenableLayout(mMainDrawerLayout)
            .build();

    View mNavigationViewHeaderView = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    mNavHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mNavigationView, mNavController);

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mMainToolbar, mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, mNavController);

    mNavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        switch (destination.getId()) {

            case R.id.homeFragment:
            case R.id.questionBankFragment:
                mMainToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                setDrawerLocked(false);
                break;


            case R.id.welcomeFragment:
            case R.id.loginFragment:
                mMainToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
                setDrawerLocked(true);
                break;

        
            case R.id.customModuleFragment:
            case R.id.createCustomModuleOneFragment:
            case R.id.createCustomModuleTwoFragment:
                mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setDrawerLocked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.logoutFragment:

                new AppSharedPreference(MainActivity.this).clearAllData();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserAuthanticationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;

        }
    });
```

It is working fine. but now i have to handle navigation on back stack that i not able to understand.

My Question is suppose i am bottom navigation There are 4 Menu. Home, Hunting , Qbank, Exam.

I am selected Qbank. Qbank have 5 fragments A, B, C, D, E.  now i have started traverse Fragment A -> B
B -> C
C -> D

and now i have choice where i have to navigate Back to Direct A like . Current position is D

D - > A

but how i can get back to A and clear stack that i traverse A -> B -> C -> D i want clear this and it's like i want to start again with A.

How I can make possible with Jetpack Navigation Component.

i tried direct navigation or popback stack navigation but it is not work it is gives me error like  if i directly navigato to

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView{98060fe VFED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0} does not have a NavController set
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
        at app.technotech.koncpt.McqTestFragment$2.onClick(McqTestFragment.java:232)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I don't have any idea how i can handle this navigation.Pleas help to fix this my solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this [A to B, B to C, and C back to A](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop)

Comment: @ॐRakeshKumar this basic navigation i want solution with bottom navigation and handle state of navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current navigation destination and pop inclusive if that's your start or desired destination

```
    if (navController.currentDestination.id == navController.graph.YOUR_PREFERED_DESTIONATION) {
    
            navController.popBackStack(
                navController.graph.YOUR_PREFERED_DESTIONATION, true
            )
    }else {
   navController.navigate(R.id.other_destination)
}
```

Comment: where i have to put this ? i think this same as above answer he showed in xml

Answer (score 0):

Use *popUpTo* to remove instances of previous Fragment from backstack and use *popUpToInclusive* to remove first instance of **A Fragment** otherwise you will have two instances of **A Fragment** in your stack:

A demo code from Android official documention:

**Navigation Graph XML View:**

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/c"
android:name="com.example.myapplication.C"
android:label="fragment_c"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c">

<action
    android:id="@+id/action_d_to_a"
    app:destination="@id/a"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/a"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Comment: it gives => does not have a NavController set.... navigation error

Answer (score 0):

**You should use different navigation graph for each bottom navigation item.**

So that each bottom menu item would have its own graph with their own starting destinations. So following this navigation path

A -> B B -> C C -> D and adding following code-

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_d_to_a"
    app:destination="@id/a"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/a"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

you can pop up to fragment A which will be a starting destination of bottom menu item and you will not get error about NavController destination.

I try to explain further with following example and code-

We have three menu item i.e. Dashboard, Find and options, in main activity I will use following code to setup bottom navigation-

```
private void setupBottomNavigation() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        List<Integer> navGraphList = new ArrayList<>();
        navGraphList.add(R.navigation.dashboard_navigation);
        navGraphList.add(R.navigation.find_navigation);
        navGraphList.add(R.navigation.options_navigation);

        LiveData<NavController> navControllerLiveData = new NavigationExtensions().setupWithNavController(
                bottomNavigationView
                , navGraphList
                , getSupportFragmentManager()
                , R.id.fragment_container, getIntent()
        );
        currentNavController = navControllerLiveData;
    }
```

**R.navigation.dashboard_navigation**, **R.navigation.find_navigation** & **R.navigation.options_navigation** will be navigation files as following-

[image]

**dashboard_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/dashboard_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/dashboardFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragment"
        android:name="your.package.DashboardFragment"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" >

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        //add other fragment to this graph

    </fragment>

<navigation>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_main"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_selector"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:itemRippleColor="?colorPrimary"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**bottom_nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/dashboard_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/dashboardTitle" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/find_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/find_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/findTitle" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/options_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/optionTitle" />

</menu>
```

Make sure menu item id match with id of navigation graph. As check for Dashboard, I have used menu item id as android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation" which is the same id, for dashboard_navigation.xml graph

[image]

You must be also using [Navigation Extension (In Kotlin)](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) provided by google itself.

To get more information on using multiple nav-graghs, click [here](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/a-useful-navigation-extension)

If you want to understand how to use Navigatin Extension File with your java code, please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251349/how-to-use-navigationextensions-kt-in-a-java-project/63186293#63186293).

Happy Coding !

Comment: if i will create each navigation graph for bottom navigation then i have create individual navigation host fragment for each graph?

Comment: @VasudevVyas host fragment will be placed inside main activity and fragment inside can be changes via navigation graph, I have uploaded main activity and menu xml in answer please check.

Comment: ` app:startDestination="fragmentid"` flag in nav-graph will decide which fragment will be starting fragment of that nav-graph. Usually we attach fragment id with bottom nav menu item but with multiple nav-graph we are attaching nav-graphs via their id to bottom nav menu.

Comment: unable to get navigation click listener... don't know whats wrong with it